# Февраль, апрель, май

Tags: этимология, заимствования

Большая часть современных месяцев названа просто порядковыми числительными: сентябрь - седьмой, октябрь - восьмой и т.д. Некоторые - в честь римских богов: январь, март. А кое-какие - в честь императоров: июль, август.
А как быть с месяцами февраль, апрель и май? От каких слов образованы их названия?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Все русские названия месяцев имеют латинское происхождение.

Февраль от Februārius mēnsis «месяц Фебрууса», «очистительный месяц» от лат. Februa «праздник очищения».
Апрель от Aprīlis — варианты: «открывающий», «согреваемый солнцем», «месяц Афродиты».
А май от имени древнеримской богини Майи.